# Relative path not resolved in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I create a module named `core` that has core functionality of the project. 
I also created a services project that used the core project in nodejs. This core module to be included as node_modules dependency (package.json) in service-app.

my service app call the core app and core app uses relative path:

---

```
//core-app -> logger.js

const loggerConfig = require('../../configs/logger-config.json');
```

When service app start then it require `core-app -> logger.js`

```
const logger = require('core');
```

than it prompt error

```
Error: Cannot find module '../../configs/logger-config.json
```

Here `../../configs/logger-config.json` is correct and it sometimes runnig on other system properly.

Now, I replace the relative path to,

```
//core-app -> logger.js
const path = require('path');
const loggerConfig = require(path.join(__dirname,'../../configs/logger-config.json'));
```

then it is running.

I resolved error but not sure about code standard. For reference, I checked the other node_modules library and found they also used relative in the same manner but my case it prompts an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__dirname` gives the current directory where the thread executes in nodejs. So, in place of relative path better to use through `__dirname`.